# Why do type 3 tests give different results than GEE for a binary predictor in SAS

Tags: p-value, sas, genmod

I'm using PROC GENMOD in SAS to model a continuous outcome as function of flight which is binary (1=yes, 0=no) and a categorical predictor (ethnicity.) So I ask PROC GENMOD to output type 3 statistics. The model outputs the slope estimate and associated p-value for each ethnicity vs. the reference, and for flight; and also the type 3 tests for ethnicity ("p-value for no effect of ethnicity") and flight ("p-value for no effect of flight.)

My question is, why are the two different ways of computing p-values for flight giving different answers? It's binary, so the global null should = the pairwise null. Right?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It would help if you could show the actual model results of the two different ways of computing p-values. Copy text output into the question, then use the `{}` code tool on the toolbar to format it in a readable form.

Comment: The annotations in your screenshot are useful, but textual information is almost always preferable - it is searchable and accessible to screen readers, which images are not.